# ISR + Code, integrating count code with ISR routine

Tags: c, embedded, pic, isr

I have a section of C code for a PIC device, it actuates 4 separate relays to a pre-defined pattern, each individually set by counting on times, and frequency of occurrence. This pattern continues ad-infinitum, but found the timing on standard delay_ms not accurate enough. I wish to convert it to ISR routine, I enclose the code below that relies on standard delay for your perusal, my main concern is how to abstract this code to ISR as I know not to stick all this code in the actual ISR routine, any advice greatly appreciated.

```
__CONFIG(FOSC_XT & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & MCLRE_OFF & CP_OFF & CPD_OFF &
        BOREN_OFF & CLKOUTEN_OFF & IESO_OFF & FCMEN_OFF);

//!!! use BORV_HI for latest PICC compiler
__CONFIG(WRT_OFF & PLLEN_OFF & STVREN_OFF & LVP_OFF);       

#define _XTAL_FREQ  4000000

unsigned long int Sample_Period =20;
unsigned long int Sample_Duration = 2;
unsigned long int Sample_ON = 0;
unsigned long int WriteTX_Period = 21;
unsigned long int WriteTX_Duration = 1; //  
unsigned long int WriteTX_ON = 0;
unsigned long int Depass_Period = 60; //every 7 days for depass event
unsigned long int Depass_Duration = 10 ; // depass for 120 seconds
unsigned long int Depass_ON = 0 ;
unsigned long int Depass_Counter = 0;
unsigned long int Sample_Counter = 0;
unsigned long int WriteTX_Counter = 0;
unsigned long int count = 0;
unsigned char input;
char data = 1;

void SkipLine(void){
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
}

void main() {
    INTCON = 0;                 // disable interrupts.
    ANSELA = 0x00;              // all digital IO
    ANSELB = 0x00;              // all digital IO
    TRISA = 0b00000000;         // Configure PORTA as output 
    PORTA = 0b00000111;         // Initialize PORTA, all load relays are off.
    ADCON0 = 7;                 // disables ADC
    CM1CON0 = 7;                // Disable analog comparators
    TRISB = 0b10111001;         // all outputs bar RB1/RX pin, and RB7 (Prog'd)

    init_comms();

    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("*******************************");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("*METROL RELAY CONTROLLER MK1.0*");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("*******************************");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");

    printf("Default timings are :");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("Sample Period = ");
    printf("%d seconds", Sample_Period);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");

    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("Sample Duration = ");
    printf("%d seconds", Sample_Duration);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");

    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("WriteTX Period = ");
    printf("%d seconds", WriteTX_Period);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");

    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("WriteTX Duration = ");
    printf("%d seconds", WriteTX_Duration);
    SkipLine;

    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("Depassivation Period (Days)= ");
    printf("%d Days", Depass_Period);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("Depassivation Duration  = ");
    printf("%d seconds", Depass_Duration);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");

    if (RB7 == 1)
    {
        printf("requires set up");

        printf("\n");
        printf("\r");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\r");

        printf("Enter value for Sample Period in minutes <0-255> ");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\r");

        char str[50];

        printf("Enter a string : ");
        gets(str);

        printf("You entered: %s", str);
        int SamplePeriodVal;
        SamplePeriodVal = atoi(str);
        printf("Sample Period Value entered = %d\n", SamplePeriodVal);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("system already configured");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");

    unsigned int Sample_Period_Units;
    Sample_Period_Units = EEPROM_READ(0x00);
    printf("sample value held in first eeprom address 0x00 is %d", EEPROM_READ(0x00));

    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");
    printf("load profile starting.....");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\r");

    while (1) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("\r");
        printf("test!");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\r");

        __delay_ms(990);

        if (Sample_Counter >= Sample_Period){
            PORTA = 0b00000110; //set Sample relay ON

            Sample_ON++;

            if (Sample_ON > Sample_Duration){
                Sample_ON = 0;
                Sample_Counter = 0;
                PORTA = 0b00000111;

            }
        }

        if (WriteTX_Counter >= WriteTX_Period){
            PORTA = 0b00000100; //set Write relay ON

            WriteTX_ON++;

            if (WriteTX_ON > WriteTX_Duration){
                WriteTX_ON = 0;
                WriteTX_Counter = 0;
                PORTA = 0b00000111;

            }
        }

        if (Depass_Counter >= Depass_Period){
            PORTA = 0b00000011; //set Depass relay ON


            Depass_ON++;

            if (Depass_ON > Depass_Duration){
                Depass_ON = 0;
                Depass_Counter = 0;
                PORTA = 0b00000111;

            }
        }

        Sample_Counter++;
        WriteTX_Counter++;
        Depass_Counter++;
        count++;            // increment total count for system

        printf("\n");
        printf("\r");

        int SampleAct;
        SampleAct = RB3;
        printf("Port B sample value =%d  ", SampleAct);

        printf("\r");
        printf("\n");

        int WriteTXAct;
        WriteTXAct = RB4;
        printf("Port B WriteTX value =%d  ", WriteTXAct);

        printf("\r");
        printf("\n");

        int DepassAct;
        DepassAct = RB5;
        printf("Port B Depass value =%d  ", DepassAct);

        printf("\r");
        printf("\n");
        printf("%ld", count);

        int PortB_Val;

        PortB_Val = PORTB & 0b00111000;

        switch (PortB_Val)
        {

        case 0x28:
            RB6 = RB6;
            printf("\n");
            printf("\r");
            printf("Sample+Depass error");
            break;

        case 0x30:
            RB6 = RB6;
            printf("\n");
            printf("\r");
            printf("Write+Depass error");
            break;

        case 0x38:
            RB6 = RB6;
            printf("\n");
            printf("\r");
            printf("Write+Sample+Depass error");
            break;

        default:
            RB6 = !RB6;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ?? once you take out the debug printf's etc, the only 'real' code is some port reads/writes.  Why can that not go in the interrupt-handler?  That control/state data with the count etc. in it should really be in one 'TimerControlBlock' struct, but that's good practice, not essential.

Comment: hi martin, i wish to keep the printf commands as health checks and even logging to serial file for proofing the system,,, but i'm concerned that type of command doesnt belong inside the ISR loop. Can i just increment all the counters in the ISR, then do my printf's outside? i measured the execution time of this code and its 97ms,,, but is this approach flawed?

Comment: "... but is this approach flawed?" No, it is broken. 1) it is nonsense to have such a bunch of "printf`s here anyway. 2) it is nonsense to have then with the functional code. 3) keeping them after testing is plain nonsense. As a proffesional, you would be gambling with your job.

Comment: And `delay`_whatever is **non-standard**.

Comment: What PIC device?  What PIC compiler?

Comment: This line: 'char data = 1;' is stuffing a integer into a char.  The better way to write it is:  'char data = '1'    The posted way results in data containing 'x01'.  The better way results in data containing an actual char: '0x31'

Comment: @user3629249 : There is a lot one could criticise in this code, but I would not start with that. Since `data` is not referenced in the code, we cannot tell what it is used for, so your criticism is unfounded.  Despite its name, in C `char` is simply an integer type and need not be used solely to represent a displayable character.  Moreover 1 or ASCII `SOH` is a perfectly valid control character in any case and may be deliberate.  I'd be more concerned about the use of [global data](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) in the first place.

Comment: You know this code would be far more succinct (and efficient) if you included the line-ends in the data output; e.g.: `printf( "Port B sample value =%d \r\n", SampleAct ) ;`  Outputting each in separate printf() calls is somewhat strange to say the least.

Comment: I suggest you pick one convention regarding where to place `{` and stick to it!

Answer (score 1):

Your code just depends on periodic timer ticks, so the general idea would be to do something like this:

```
volatile static uint8_t tick;

ISR(TIMER_vec) /* whatever int vector is triggered by your timer */
{
    ++tick;
}


int main () {
    /* [...] */

    while (1)
    {
        uint8_t lasttick = 0;
        while (tick != lasttick)
        {
            lasttick = tick; /* or ++lasttick; for handling "missed" interrupts late */

            /*
             * do your periodic stuff here
             */
        }
        /* wait for next interrupt, e.g. by entering sleep state
           for AVR: */
        sleep_cpu();
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to arrange for getting your timer interrupt, depending on your chip. If things get more complex, you could be interested in [some code I wrote](https://github.com/Zirias/shuttercontrol/blob/master/shutterctl_attiny84/event.c) using ISRs to fill an event queue.

Comment: lasttick should be initialized to tick, not zero.

Comment: @Lundin that's the same, because `tick` has static storage (implicitly initialized to zero)

Comment: No it is not, because a variable amount of time has passed from the point where you initialized the timer to the point where the code is executed. Furthermore, it is very common for embedded systems to not implement the standard static initialization, and it is actually not even needed in this case, as the actual value of `tick` is irrelevant for the program to function.

Comment: @Lundin: 1. avr-libc implements it, if it's NOT implemented, you could STILL initialize it to 0, 2. you typically set up your interrupts last before entering your event loop, 3. using 0 here allows for a design where ticks should still be handled late (design decision, depending on your needs). So, just leave details to the reader, this is to present the general idea. For possible relevance of the actual value of `tick`, see comment in the inner loop.

Comment: I see a bad race condition: what if the interrupt hits in `sleep_cpu`? Good application for `stdatomic`.

Comment: @Olaf, have to check that. A problem could occur when an interrupt is served directly before the "sleep" instruction. Simplest thing to do here is not attempting to sleep, but that could be wasteful

Comment: The problem is the test and update of `tick` are non-atomic. Also setting `lasttick` to zero is questionable. Anyway, the few ports could more easily be set in the ISR with the main-loop just waking up to update user-status (e.g. these little-use `printf`s). That would also reduce jitter massively.

Comment: @Olaf that's only a problem if you're concerned about "missing" an interrupt, not a concern in this basic schema, but *might* be. On the other hand, the issue with "sleep", although unlikely, is quite bad, having to wait for the next interrupt although one is pending. I'll have to look into *that*, just a basic atomic operation won't help here.

Comment: @Olaf the version for not missing ANY interrupt is in the comment and there is no race without any atomics ... it's quite similar to my "real-life" code. The real problem with this solution is indeed `sleep`... I'll consult the specs *again* to see whether there is a solution.

Comment: @Olaf and indeed, when setting the interrupt flag on an AVR, interrupts are allowed only one instruction *later*, so the clue here would be `cli(); if (tick == lasttick) { sei(); cpu_sleep(); } else sei();` -- I'll update my real-life code, thanks for the hint, but not this answer because I feel this is too machine-specific...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I'd call having an interrupt passing by undetected very well a fault. For the link: I do not accept external-only references as part of an answer. Anyway, that would be much easier if you just wait until `tick` has changed from `lasttick`. The code would then execute in the outer loop (the "inner" is empty). That would require another temp var for the wait-loop. My other issues (jitter, etc.) might still apply.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I did not go into PIC that deep (glad I had to use it many years ago only). However, That might be better assembler code to ensure the compiler will not interfere in the sequence.

Comment: @Olaf -- as I said, I gave an example here for AVR (not knowing PIC) and avr-gcc guarantees you to emit *just* a `sei` instruction for `sei()` and *just* a `sleep` for `cpu_sleep()`, so this *will* work as expected. For everythign else, feel free to give a different answer. Many things depend on what you actually want to do and I only took into account the OP not wanting to put all his code inside the ISR.

Comment: Hmm, I did not find that in the answer. Might have overread in a comment - sorry. However, I do not use AVR either. Just the lesser crap of an MCU with an 80ies/early 90ies architecture.

Comment: Regarding the init of lasttick, my advise will never do any harm, but in some cases lead to more robust code. Even if you enable interrupts just before the loop, you'll have the latency of [timer setup] + [loop overhead] + [lasttick initialization time] + [ISR calling overhead], as opposed to just [ISR calling overhead]. Keep in mind that this is a PIC, the slowest piece of 80s crap still produced.

Comment: @Lundin, it depends on whether you're after *exact timing* or *handling each and every interrupt, no matter when*. Initializing `lasttick` to `tick` would favour the first. So I still declare this a design decision (that should be decided knowing the implications). It's probably out of scope of this sketched-up answer.

Comment: @Olaf What makes you think `tick` is non-atomic? You'll have to disassemble the code to tell, it will be highly dependent on the CPU core and compiler. The `++tick;` inside the ISR can never be a problem, because when the ISR is executed, the main program will not be interrupted. Only the reads of `tick` in the main loop could cause problems. In which case main should be rewritten as `while ((tmp=tick) != lasttick) { lasttick = tmp;`. I'm pretty sure the read of `tick` will be atomic on most MCUs.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm considering the case where the timer has been already been running so long that `lasttick` happen to equal `tick` at the point when the loop condition is executed for the first time. It may not be an issue at all, still `lasttick = tick;` as initialization couldn't cause any harm.

Comment: @Lundin: the whole `while (tick != lasttick) { lasttick = tick;` sequence is non-atomic, but I'd argue it doesn't matter because this is the flavour of code for cases where missing a tick is better than handling it late. The alternative is in the comment (`++lasttick`) and doesn't need atomic operation to work properly.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose one could just toss both of the counters out in file scope, compare them inside the ISR and then set a bool flag when the comparison hits. Should solve all timing and re-entrancy issues both.

Comment: @Lundin a boolean flag will only do *when* you want to drop ticks (more than one) that might happen while you still handle the last one. Again, it depends on the use case...

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the precision of delay_ms() is determined exactly by the stability of your XTAL - it is unlikly that that is your problem unless you are running on a low precision RC oscilator, and if that is the case, using timer hardware or an ISR will not help as they all run on the same clock.

Your problem is rather your design and the use of  printf().  If printf() is unbuffered, or you are filling the buffer, then the loop time will be dominated by the debug output - if the printf() output is via a UART serial port, the loop time will be determined by the baud rate of that channel and the amount of text output.

The fundamental problem is that your loop time is the sum of the delay *plus* the time to execute the loop body - which is probably variable and non-deterministic depending on the implementation of printf, the output device, its data rate and whether there is flow control for example.

A better method would be to poll a timer and execute the loop-body when it becomes time to do so rather than after a fixed delay. Implementation of a timer is platform specific, but assuming you implement a timer whose ISR increments a counter every millisecond, and the counter is read by a function `gettime_ms()`, then your loop becomes:

```
int start_1000 = gettime_ms() ;
int now = start ;
for(;;)
{
    now = gettime_ms() ;

    if( now - start_1000 >= 1000 )
    {
        start_1000 += 1000 ;

        //  Loop body here - will execute every 1000ms
        // so long as the loop body takes less than 1000ms in total.
        ...
    }
}
```

You can then easily introduce other periodic operations at different rates:

```
int now = gettime_ms() ;
int start_1000 = now;
int start_50 = now ;

for(;;)
{
    now = gettime_ms() ;

    // Every second
    if( now - start_1000 >= 1000 )
    {
        start_1000 += 1000 ;

        // 1 second operations here
        ...
    }

    // Every 50ms
    if( now - start_50 >= 50)
    {
        start_50 += 50 ;

        // 50ms operations here 
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also do fast background task work outside of periodic blocks so that you can make best use of available CPU time.  Such tasks might include safety monitoring for example - not something you would want to wait a whole second for perhaps.

Ultimately if there are significantly time critical tasks and event handling to perform, then an RTOS might be in order.

Comment: @olaf the outputs of sprintfs are used to log data for post processing, the lack of these would indeed cause issues with my job, there is a datastream coming from National Instruments hardware and the serial data is core to our results, sprintf is staying,,,,,,,   thanks for all input, i will tidy my codes, many thanks gents...

Comment: the main loop in my code takes less than 100ms, so i will put that in the tidied codes ISR routine, thanks all,,,,

Comment: @StevieB : As a rule, 100ms is far too long for ISR code. Lower priority interrupts will be delayed and become non-deterministic.